# How to change the chapter header font/layout?

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I'm trying to make a chapter header style to mimic the image as follows:

[image]

I've got the following code currently, but not sure how to get the line in the middle, and the title of the chapter to be below the chapter number.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge}{\Large CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter\newline}{0pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Turing Machines}
\end{document}
```

Also related to this task: I'd like to know if there's any way to selectively customize the font of a section header without having to change the default font of the whole document. I'm using `pdflatex` on Windows via MiKTeX, and one package I tried - I forget the name of it now, but I think it might have been `fontspec` - wouldn't work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: `fontspec` only works with XeTeX and LuaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this through usage of tikz.

Ignore the text - that's a work in progress, as well as the formatting for it all. But I got the chapter header just how I wanted it, which after playing around turned out to be a bit different than the image above.

[image]

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,-1) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{white}\LARGE CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
              {\color{cyan}\Huge\MakeUppercase{#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
\end{chapter}
```

I'm using a custom made class file, so I only included what I think is the bare minimum to get the heading to show... it won't ultimately look exactly like in this image with the spacing and other text positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little code that I took from a German website some times ago (I can not find it to reference sadly). With a little modification it is *partially* similar to what you are looking for. Maybe it can be a good starting point:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{chapter}{cyan}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{chapter}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \begin{picture}(40,30)(0,5)
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
        \put(0,15){\line(1,0){\dimexpr
                \textwidth-1\unitlength\relax\@gobble}}
            \put(40,15){\makebox(\dimexpr
            \textwidth-20\unitlength\relax\@gobble,\ht\strutbox\@gobble)[l]{
            \ \normalsize\color{cyan}\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot
          }}
    \end{picture}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Alan Turing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does indeed look similar, but one big difference is the fact that the line doesn't extend to the edge of the page; it only reaches the margins. I'll see if I can get it working though, since it is pretty close.

Comment: @agent154, You are right! I didn't pay attention to the line. But again, I thought it's close enough and can be a starting point. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother


\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
    {}{0pt}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \node(chapter)[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{cyan}\normalsize CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
                \gettikzxy{(chapter)}{\chapterx}{\chaptery}
                \draw[color=cyan] (0,\chaptery-25) -- ++ (\paperwidth,0);
                \node[anchor=west,xshift=.21\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{cyan}\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
        \chapter{Speaking mathematically}
\end{document}
```