# Dynamic margin, custom chapter title design

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I'm pretty new to Latex, and I hit a bit of a road block getting something to work. I'm using the tikz and titlesec package to generate a custom header design. The problem I'm having is in finding a way to make the body text start a certain margin under the chapter title (the height is dependent on the chapter name length) so I don't know if there is way to do this in a dynamic  way.

Thanks for your time.

(Orginal source of tkitz chapter latex code: [How to change the chapter header font/layout?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95892/how-to-change-the-chapter-header-font-layout?rq=1))

Sample code:

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
 \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
    {}{0pt}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north west)
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \node(chapter)[text width=10cm,anchor=west,xshift=.128\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{black}\normalsize CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
                \gettikzxy{(chapter)}{\chapterx}{\chaptery}
                \draw[color=black] (0,\chaptery-25) -- ++ (\paperwidth,0);
                \node[text width=13cm,anchor=north west,xshift=.128\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{black}\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Full code as sugested below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=17cm,
  paperheight=24cm,
  bottom = 2cm,
  top = 2cm
  % other options
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ppl}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection }{1em}{#1}




\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\scshape}
    {}{0pt}
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north west)
            {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \node(chapter)[text width=10cm,anchor=west,xshift=.128\paperwidth,yshift=-.01\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{black}\normalsize CHAPTER \Huge\thechapter};
                \gettikzxy{(chapter)}{\chapterx}{\chaptery}
                \draw[color=black] (0,\chaptery-25) -- ++ (\paperwidth,0);
                \node[text width=13cm,anchor=north west,xshift=.128\paperwidth,yshift=-.065\paperheight,rectangle]
                            {\color{black}\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}



\makeatletter
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\footrulewidth}}
    \vskip\footruleskip}}
\makeatother
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\headruleskip\vskip-\headrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\headrulewidth}}
    \vskip\headruleskip}}
\makeatother


\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily \fontsize{8}{8} \slshape \rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\fontsize{8}{8} }
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily \thepage}% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily \thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}

\begin{document}

        \chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit vivamus feugiat.}

\lipsum[4]
\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[1-18]

 \chapter{Introduzione}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! 1) Could you post a *full* compilable code? 2) Are you sure such a layout requires a hammersledge like TikZ?

Comment: Thank you, The chapter design is based of an example I found online that I edited to fit my needs, another suggestion of how todo it in a simpler way is always welcome. I updated the question with the full code of the document as it is at this moment.

Comment: Why do you load `palatino` in addition to `kpfonts`?

Comment: I just looked up the docs for kpfonts and that is indeed a valid point, I will be removing the palantino package. Pointers like that are greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems they use palatino as a ttfont (???). Other than that, There's an error message with you code:  `\headruleskip` is undefined. Anyway, what are you trying to obtain? a rule that goes throughout the physical page, between the chapter number and the chapter title?

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to the chapter title bleeding into the text below, so I am looking for a way to get the text to start after the chapter title. The screenshot shows the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to find a simple solution, and I'd bet tikz isn't required – as far as I can guess what you want  from the mage in your post.

Comment: Do you have a link to the place online you got the code? You should include an attribution/link in your question/code.

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s is unsupported and a known source of problems. It ought not be done.

Comment: @Bernard Where's the tt-font bit?

Comment: There was somewhere in the preamble (maybe commented): `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ppl}
` but it seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Note that I cannot recommend `titlesec` because it never works for me. However, I seem able to use it to answer other people's questions.*
>
> ## *Caveat emptor ...*

This presumably gives bad box warnings, so certainly needs tidying, but maybe it is a start. I've commented both `palatino` and `helvet`. Either you want `kpfonts` or you don't. If you do, don't overwrite the changes; if you don't, don't load those changes in the first place.

This avoids Ti*k*Z but, despite my qualms, keeps `titlesec`. It requires `calc`. I've added `showframe` to `geometry`'s options, to show the placement of elements on the page. Obviously you should delete this in your real document. I used it to match the placement of 'CHAPTER \thechapter' to the point at which it was placed by your code. The other spacings are eye-balled, but may easily be adjusted as desired.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
% \usepackage{helvet} % this an the next line partly overwrite kpfonts - either remove the kpfonts line or remove these; if you remove the kpfonts line, consider using one of the packages which configures all your fonts to include palatino & helvetica clones
% \usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=17cm,
  paperheight=24cm,
  bottom = 2cm,
  top = 2cm,
  showframe,
  % other options
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ppl}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
    \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
    \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\sffamily\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection }{1em}{#1}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\sffamily}
    {}{0pt}
    {%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \normalsize CHAPTER {\Huge\thechapter}\\[-\baselineskip]
        \hspace*{-\Gm@lmargin}\vrule height 0.4pt width \paperwidth\\
        \Huge\bfseries\raggedright\MakeUppercase{#1}
      \end{minipage}%
    }
\makeatother
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{20pt}% adjust the last value to change the space between title and text

\makeatletter
\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\footrulewidth}}
    \vskip\footruleskip}}
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\headsep\vskip-\headrulewidth
    \leavevmode\rlap{\hspace*{-2in}\rule{2\paperwidth}{\headrulewidth}}
    \vskip\headsep}}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily \fontsize{8}{8} \slshape \rightmark}%
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\fontsize{8}{8} }%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily \thepage}% Custom footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}

% Redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily \thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}% Line at the header invisible
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the footer visible
}
\pagestyle{IHA-fancy-style}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit vivamus feugiat.}

\lipsum[4]
\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[1-18]

\chapter{Introduzione}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter with long title]

[image: chapter with short title]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and yes your solution is so much cleaner then using tikz, I will look for the url of where I found the header example and edit my question to add it.